# Протокол Диффи-Хеллмана не работает при некоторых значениях

Tags: c++, криптография

Почему при

> p = 23, g = 5, a = 6, b = 15

ba равен ab, но при

> p = 23, g = 5, a = 116, b = 15

уже нет?

Какие типы, числа и диапазоны чисел должны быть для этого протокола?

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 

int main() {
  unsigned long long int p = 23;
  unsigned long long int g = 5;
  unsigned long long int a = 6;
  unsigned long long int b = 15;
  unsigned long long int A = std::fmod(pow(g, a), p);
  unsigned long long int B = std::fmod(pow(g, b), p);
  unsigned long long int ba = std::fmod(pow(B, a), p);
  unsigned long long int ab = std::fmod(pow(A, b), p);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Вся хитрость в простых числах.

Comment: @NewView числа должны быть простыми?

Comment: @AnT fmod не точный?

Comment: На сколько я помню, при генерации таблиц DH используются простые числа, смотрел правда давно и на openssl, а там в исходниках чёрт ногу сломит :)

Comment: @Mike Waters: Все вычисления с плавающей точкой - в общем случае неточные.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, в криптографических алгоритмах нужны точные целочисленные вычисления. Вы же используете приближенные вычисления с плавающей точкой. Ни о каком точном вычислении 5<sup>116</sup> в вашем варианте речи идти не будет - это слишком большое число.

Во-вторых, ваша последовательность действий описывает процесс формирования общего ключа после выбора секретных ключей `a` и `b`. В протоколе Диффи-Хеллмана секретные ключи `a` и `b` выбираются из мультипликативной группы по модулю `p`, то есть в вашем примере для `p = 23` это должны быть значения в диапазоне `[1, 22]`. При чем здесь ваше `116`, откуда вы его взяли и чего от него ожидали - не ясно.

(Как правильно заметил @Zergatul в комментариях, при `p = 23` протокол будет правильно работать и для `a = 116`. Но нет никакого смысла в том, чтобы выбирать число за пределами диапазона `[1, 22]`. В вашем случае это лишь привело к потере точности.)

Comment: Если придираться, то значение 116 здесь ничего не сломает. Все равно в итоге берется модуль, и получится число меньше 23. Другими словами, вместо числа `a`, мы можем взять любое `a + x * 23`. Главное что бы 116 не делилось на 23.

Answer (score 2):

Никто так не считает остаток от деления после возведения в степень. Самая простая оптимизация выглядит так:

```
int modpow(int a, int b, int m) // a^b % m
{
    int result = 1;
    // 31 - для упрощения кода, на самом деле нужно брать длину числа в битах
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result = result * result % m;
        if (b & (1 << i))
            result = result * a % m;
    }
    return result;
}
```

В реальных библиотеках для длинных чисел и криптографии дополнительно используют [алгоритм Монтгомери](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8).

Comment: а можно пример на C++ вычисления за алгоритмом Монтгомери? Искал в Google и какбы безуспешно, в математике я не особо силен) а более быстрому решению всегда рад

Comment: @MikeWaters Монгомери есть смысл использовать только на очень больших числах, которые применяются в криптографии. Порядка 200+ бит. Если вы работаете со стандартными типами int/long и т. д., то ускорения вы не получите.